# How to have routes aliases?

Tags: asp.net-core, asp.net-core-mvc, asp.net-core-1.0, asp.net-core-middleware

I look for create a routing system using aliases with ASP.NET Core.

In my database, i have all my routes with the corresponding aliases, when an user request the server my app look for the route corresponding with the alias.

Now, I want to use the recovered route to access the right controller and the right action.

An example will be more explicit than a long speech (what I want to do is in brackets):

The user connects to myapp.com/hello/i/am/an/alias -> The app finds the corresponding route that is /MyController/Index ( -> The app uses MyController to send the Index view to the user )

If someone knows how to do, i take :D thanks

Edit: Actually, the better will be to edit the HttpContext, but I don't think it is possible

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, i found the answer !!

It is possible to edit the path in the context like that:
`context.Request.Path = new PathString(newPath);`

so i used a MapWhen that always return true and edits the context.Request.Path with the database's response and the mapHandler just call app.UseMvc:

```
private void HandleMap(IApplicationBuilder app)
    {
        app.UseMvc(routes =>
        {
            routes.MapRoute(
                name: "default",
                template: "{controller=Home}/{action=Index}/{id?}");
        });
    }

app.MapWhen(context => {
            string newPath = findNewPath();

            context.Request.Path = new PathString(newPath);

            return true;
        }, HandleMap);
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you'll want to run something like this in the Configure method of Startup.cs

```
app.UseMvc(routes =>
{
    routes.MapRoute(
        name: "path1",
        template: "hello/i/am/an/alias",
        defaults: {controller="MyController", action="Index"});

    routes.MapRoute(
        name: "path2",
        template: "i/am/another/alias",
        defaults: {controller="MyOtherController", action="Index"});

    // etc.
});
```

Comment: I suspect he wants it dynamic and from database, like the slug (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Semantic_URL#Slug) used in CMS systems which would require to rebuild the route tables everytime a new slug gets created at runtime which isn't recommended

Comment: Yes Tseng, it's something like that